# WPF datagrid autoresize on maximize

Tags: wpf

My WPF application has a resolution of 1024x768. I have a `datagrid` that fills a vertical half of the application. In higher resolutions, when I maximize I want the `datagrid` to automatically resize vertically and fill the entire height. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean fill the entire height of the screen, or just the extra space?  Or by "vertical half" do you mean it's the left or right half of the screen from top to bottom already?

Answer (score 2):

you can try setting the control's vertical alignment to stretch (`VeritcalAlignment="Stretch"`) so that even when your window resizes, it still fills up the vertical part of your screen.

Let me know if this works for you or you have something else in mind. :)

Answer (score -2):

So if I understand your question correctly, you are asking that if your screen resolution is higher than 1024 X 768 and application is maximized you want DataGrid to fill the entire height.  You should register application size change event. Inside that event you should get the current screen resolution and if the current screen resolution is greater than 1024 x 768 you can set the DataGrid height to * so that it can cover the whole available space.

Comment: NO!  UI changes in code are almost never necessary, and using `*` for height only works if you're resizing a grid column or row.  Setting a DataGrid's height to `*` wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @Dan Puzey: oh.. I should have said the container that contains the DataGrid.. for example a Grid's row.. I definitely would like to know how you can fulfill such a requirement with out code that do something with UI..